# Cordova plugin video editor: AVC video profile is not supported by Android OS, actual profile_idc: 100

Tags: cordova, github, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, video-compression

I've been using [this plugin to do video compression](https://github.com/jbavari/cordova-plugin-video-editor.git) and it works fine for most cases.  However, on some phones, notably Huawei and Xiaomi, it fails to compress video with the error:

```
net.ypresto.androidtranscoder.engine.InvalidOutputFormatException:   
Non-baseline AVC video profile is not supported by Android OS, actual profile_idc: 100
```

**Q) Is there any simple/obvious way to fix this, or can someone point me to a fork that is up-to-date that fixes this problem?**